# TypeError: Result of expression 'audio.play' [undefined] is not a function. in iphone

Tags: iphone, safari, html5-audio

Audio tag not working in iPhone first time it is work fine futher it is not working. Other browsers like firefox, chrome & mac it's working but in iPhone not working. Please help below is the code.

```
  $('.confirmonbutton').click(function (){ 
        var audio = jQuery("#audio")[0];
       audio.play();
});
 </head>
<body>
      <audio  id="audio" onended="myFunction()" type="audio/mpeg" src="sounds/500 Hz 60 dB Left.mp3" ></audio>
    <script>
function myFunction() {
 //some script here...
}
    </script>
    </body>
```

Comment: Is this the actual code (running a script directly inside the head tag)?

Comment: yes but brief overview here ken. It's working fine on iOS first time  button second  time not. I think audio object no reinitialized  again. pls help